# the screen rendering of 17.10 with intel i5-8400 is really slow

Tags: intel-graphics, 17.10

I just bought a computer and install ubuntu 17.10 but the graph rendering is really slow.

It just like using windows without installing VGA driver except I can get the resolution of 1920x1080.

I also checked Software & updates > additional Drivers.

There is a message shown that

```
unknown:unknown
This device is using an alternative driver.
```

How can I solve this problem?

My hardware is :

```
intel i5-8400
msi z370 tomahawk
```

the message came after vainfo:

```
libva info: VA-API version 0.40.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 17.10 is currently shipping kernel version 4.13. But the graphics driver for 8th generation coffee lake processors are merged in kernel mainline for version 4.15. ([source](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-4.15-CFL-No-Alpha))

Currently you can install 4.15 kernel Ubuntu builds to fix the graphics issue.

Download these debian packages

```
mkdir -p ~/linux_4.15 && cd ~/linux_4.15

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/daily/2018-01-01/linux-headers-4.15.0-999-generic_4.15.0-999.201801010200_amd64.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/daily/2018-01-01/linux-headers-4.15.0-999_4.15.0-999.201801010200_all.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/daily/2018-01-01/linux-image-4.15.0-999-generic_4.15.0-999.201801010200_amd64.deb

dpkg -i *.deb

sudo update-grub

sudo reboot
```

Ubuntu should boot with the latest kernel image now. Your graphics rendering should be smooth.

Comment: All the links mentioned for the kernel are going to 404 Not Found error. Would you mind adding working links? I  am using ubuntu 16.04 with i58400 and currently the system is barely usable due to graphics issue. Thanks

Comment: debian packages are not kept for all the builds. They keep packages for some 7-8 builds. Use these links for now

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.15/linux-headers-4.15.0-041500-generic_4.15.0-041500.201802011154_amd64.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.15/linux-headers-4.15.0-041500_4.15.0-041500.201802011154_all.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.15/linux-image-4.15.0-041500-generic_4.15.0-041500.201802011154_amd64.deb

Answer (score 0):

Here the correct link http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.15/
After installing the kernel 4.15 the graphics rendering works fine.
But after really don't works the broadcom wifi card and the command "apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source" don't works because he don't reinstall on this kernel.

Now i solved reinstalling kernel 4.13.0-36-generic and then following this: http://joshuakanz.com/ubuntu/Coffee-Lake-GPU-Linux-Alpha-Support/
after the recboot all so good.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to linux kernel v4.15 resolved the issue.

I used the UKUU tool to manage and upgrade the linux kernel to v4.15 and it was all great after the reboot.

If you do not want to install/manage/update kernel manually through terminal, UKUU tool is the best.

Find more over here in regards to installing UKUU [HERE](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/ukuu-easy-way-to-install-mainline-kernel-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

As the Ercole Comini said [this link](http://joshuakanz.com/ubuntu/Coffee-Lake-GPU-Linux-Alpha-Support/) worked perfectly for me. My processor is Intel i5 8400.

For the sake of simplicity I am writing those steps here directly.

1. Copy and paste the following:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.alpha_support=1"
   ```
2. Open the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
3. Edit your Grub file.

   ```
   sudoedit /etc/default/grub
   ```
4. Find `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` and replace it with what you copied from step 1.
5. Save the Grub file.
6. Update Grub.

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
7. Reboot.

This solution may vary according to your configuration, so please do this on your own risk.