# Slow graphics on i7-8700k UHD 630 ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: gpu-driver

Recently installed Ubuntu to my new Build with 8700k but integrated graphics are dead slow. I almost cannot use the OS.

Any suggestions? Try Ubuntu 17?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Puneet from [the screen rendering of 17.10 with intel i5-8400 is really slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973212/the-screen-rendering-of-17-10-with-intel-i5-8400-is-really-slow)

> Ubuntu 17.10 is currently shipping kernel version 4.13. But the graphics driver for 8th generation coffee lake processors are merged in kernel mainline for version 4.15. (source)
>
> Currently you can install 4.15 kernel Ubuntu builds to fix the graphics issue.
>
> Download these debian packages
>
> ```
> mkdir -p ~/linux_4.15 && cd ~/linux_4.15
>
> wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/daily/2018-01-01/linux-headers-4.15.0-999-generic_4.15.0-999.201801010200_amd64.deb
>
> wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/daily/2018-01-01/linux-headers-4.15.0-999_4.15.0-999.201801010200_all.deb
>
> wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/daily/2018-01-01/linux-image-4.15.0-999-generic_4.15.0-999.201801010200_amd64.deb
>
> dpkg -i *.deb
>
> sudo update-grub
>
> sudo reboot
> ```

It actually works fine for me with Ubuntu 16.04 too.

Comment: I followed the http://omgfoss.com/install-kernel-4-15-x-32-bit-ubuntu/
RC8 worked just great!